# Populate template variable from server method callback in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, meteor, callback

I am computing a data array in a server method using `meteorhacks:aggregate` (https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate).

I want to populate my template with the data array with a template helper.

How can I do this? I have tried running the method in an `onCreated` function and save the output in a callback to a reactive variable, and then show the value of the reactive variable in the helpers. The problem is that reactive variables cannot hold arrays, so it doesn't work.

The output doesn't have to be reactive, so I guess it's quite easy. Actually, I can't understand why it is not possible to just return the output in the callback directly in the helper? It doesn't write any error message, but the variable is just not populated correctly.

Comment: Instead of ReactiveVar, try the https://github.com/ManuelDeLeon/ReactiveArray/ package to store the value returned from the method.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't understand why it is not possible to just return the output in the callback directly in the helper?

Because helpers are called synchronously and method calls are asynchronous.